# Retrieving Array from API and filtering through in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have successfully called and passed the token to my API endpoint. However, I do not need both objects. I just want to work with the first index in the array that has fields. So I would like to retrieve all the details and print them out in the browser but for now all what can be printed is ID and type

[image]

I have tried filtering through the data array but it did not work.

```
var config = {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer token'}
};

class App extends React.Component  {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       data: [],
     }
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     axios.get('https://api.transferwise.com/v1/profiles',config)
       .then(response => {
         if (response.status === 200 && response != null) {
           this.setState({
             data: response.data
           });
         } else {
           console.log('problem');
         }
       })
       .catch(error => {
         console.log(error);
       });
     }

     render() {
       const { data } = this.state;
       return (
         <div >
           {this.state.data.map(object => (
             <p key={object.uid}>{object.id} {object.type}</p>
           ))}
         </div>
       )
     }};

export default App;
```

Comment: "first index in the array that has fields" which fields? Sounds like you're looking for `Array#find`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Hey thank you for responding, I have attached a screenshot, so I just want to retrieve for example firstName from the first object in the array

Comment: Depends what you want `this.state.data` to be. If you want it to be just the first name, `this.setState({ data: response.data[0].details.firstName })`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your data consists of an array where each item can be an object with details of a different type.

To dynamically render the field values of each object you could do something like:

```
{this.state.data.map(({ id, type, details }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p key={id}>
        {id} {type}
      </p>

      {Object.keys(details).map((key, index) => (
        <p key={index}>{details[key]}</p>
      ))}
    </>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Hey dude, thank you for your answer, after trying this, I receive the following

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, registrationNumber, acn, abn, arbn, companyType, companyRole, descriptionOfBusiness, primaryAddress, webpage, businessCategory, businessSubCategory}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Hey just updated to address your nested data structure. Give that a shot

Comment: Hey, your answer totally makes sense but I am stuck due to braces issues and can't sort it out for some reason

Line 36:  Your render method should have return statement  react/require-render-return  / or unexpected token

Answer (score 0):

So it looks to me like you're not going deep enough in your mapped object.
which means you should access the details portion of the object to get the info you want

```
this.state.data.map(object => (
   // The object data structure at this point should look like this
   // {
   //  details: {firstName: 'firstExample', lastName: 'lastExample', ...},
   //  id: 'example'
   //  type: 'personal'
   // } if you console.log(object) you should be able to see it

   {<p key={object.details.id}>{object.details.id} {object.details.type}</p>
))}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have tried this and nothing prints out, I am sorry if its some basic question I am asking, I cannot figure it out for some reason